# TCP chat server architecture in node.js… saving socket in database or in memory?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, tcp, chat

I am planing a TCP chat server in node.js+mongo db.. here is what I am thinking for the architecture -

- Create a collection in mongo db "online_users" this collection will have all the online users and once user get offline I'll remove those users from this collection.
- Create a collection "rooms".. in this collection I am planing to store room name (consist of a csv of username in the room) and participants in this room..
- History collection for storing chat history for users.

Now I am thinking for store socket connections in the database in "rooms" collection, but I am not sure if I should have do that or store socket connections inside Array?

Here is the flow with database I am thinking -

If user A start chatting with B and C, then I'll create a new room "A,B,C". I'll send this room name to client and chat client will have to pass this room name when sending new chat msgs.  When user a send msg in the chat  I'll check in which room they are in and get everybody's socket connection from database and will broadcast that msg to B and C.

Please note I am new to node.js and chat servers so I am open to any suggestions on the architecture. Also if you have any links for TCP chat server architecture / chat server database architecture.. then please do share in your comments/answers.

Any help would me much appreciated!!

**Update 1 :** Also I am not sure if I can store socket objects in database :( .. serialization might work? let me know thoughts on this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming to Node.JS from, lets say PHP, have to **introduce rethinking** over the way things are done, this especially covers networking.

Huge advantage in node that it is **single process**, and everything happening in one process with shared memory. It is not limited/closed connections/requests like in PHP for each request. But just events and data from them, whether they coming from database, http or tcp socket, and other IOs.

Taking that in account, it is not necessary to have extra application/layer for exchange of data, as it can be exchanged straight away inside node.js.

As Chat is **real-time** application time (not as games though), it would be **unnecessary to store everything in database**, in fact most of things should not be in database, as it would be **bottleneck**.
You can easily create array of rooms (or object with key==id, value==room), that each room will have own list of users and will cover all the logic inside.

It all can be done in node.js without need of database at all. That makes it much more efficient, but a bit less scalable, but scalability is totally different topic anyway and have to be discussed differently.

Split logic into Objects, think abstract. Room - is independant thing, as well as users, as well as messages, but they all are related.
Use **OOP** in javascript - that will help a lot.

What will be you client application? I would suggest to use browser as client, and [**socket.io**](http://socket.io/) as communication layer. That is very efficient, scalable and easy way of making this sort of applications.
Especially for learning node and its powers.

Sockets - is OS related processes, and node only have pointers to them and extra layers for ease of use for developers. Your thinking about them is well, totally 'wrong' and consideration of 'storing' sockets in database shows huge lack of experience which you mentioned. In fact there is no way of storing OS IO things in databases or sort of, and no need at all. Just try start from simple things, like socket.io, and progress with time. Do not compare things with PHP (for example) as it will slow you down pretty much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! two things - First - If I'll have everything in node.js, without database what will happen if it get restarted or server restarted? I'll loose all socket connections right? Second - I don't think I can create a TCP server with Socket.io or can we? my client apps will be on iPhone, android, BB and WP8. I don't think I can use websockets natively on these platforms.

Comment: Also if you know any link or study material regarding building multi room chat servers with node.js then please share.. will be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't seen any particular. In fact it is well easy thing to do, you just need to get into concepts of node.js and socket.io, than it will be very clear and easy of how to make rooms. I recommend of not using default rooms in socket.io but make your own stuff. Join, Leave, Post and other methods to rooms. Room - is just list of users/sockets in it.